# Most efficient way to concat rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, relational-database, aggregate-functions, group-concat

My SQL knowledge is really bit rusty but I have a somewhat easy question for the experts. I have three tables:

posts
 - post_id
 - name
 - description

posts_categories
 - post_id
 - slug

posts_themes
 - post_id
 - slug

Basically I'd like to query a list of posts like so:

```
SELECT post_id, name, description, themes, categories FROM posts LIMIT 0, 50
```

I'd like to combine the relevant categories & theme tables and concatenate them into a single column. So my output would be:

1 | testing | description | music,art,history | important,relevant,new

I've attempted this as a subquery but hit the common issue where multiple rows are returned. I've also attempted LEFT JOIN'ing the results but I can't seem to get the correct results returned. For fear of buggering my results without realizing it I was hoping someone could help formulate the most efficient and correct query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your main table (posts), you could do regular joins with the theme and category tables. Left joins are used in this case to allow for rows that don't have a category or theme to show up in the result.

To get the comma separated values you then group by the values from `posts` (the ones that should have a single value per row) and use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to comma separate the non grouped values, something like;

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.name, p.description,
   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(pc.slug), '') categories,
   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(pt.slug), '') themes
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_categories pc ON p.post_id = pc.post_id
LEFT JOIN posts_themes pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
GROUP BY p.post_id, p.name, p.description
ORDER BY p.post_id, p.name, p.description
LIMIT 50
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/514b3/2).

Comment: I like your solution more than Ollie Jone's, however I don't know why it's necessary to group by the name and description. Also I'm getting duplicate results in my dataset. How can I ensure they are unique? I believe throwing DISTINCT() before the GROUP_CONCAT would work.

Comment: @ddibiase In MySQL, you can group by only id in the case that id is unique enough, however other RDBMS's (postgresql/sql server/oracle/...) or even some modes MySQL can be set to are stricter and require you to group by all single values. I'm not sure what kind of duplicates you're getting, could you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

You are a future satisfied customer of [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Consider this subquery:

```
SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(slug) AS slugs
  FROM posts_categories
 GROUP BY post_id
```

It will give you the comma-separated list of category slugs by post. A similar query will give you the themes slugs.

Then, you simply join these subqueries, getting this.

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.name, a.description,
       b.slugs AS categories,
       c.slugs AS themes
  FROM posts AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(slug) AS slugs
            FROM posts_categories
           GROUP BY post_id
       ) AS b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(slug) AS slugs
            FROM posts_themes
           GROUP BY post_id
       ) AS c ON a.post_id = c.post_id
 ORDER BY a.post_id
```

The trick is to create the correct summaries as subqueries, then join them to the posts table.

Note: if you were handling only categories or only themes, you could avoid the subquery, just LEFT JOIN the posts_categories table, and do a GROUP BY on the main query. But if you join both the `post_categories` and `posts_themes` tables you'll get a combinatorial explosion and a lot of extra data in your comma separated lists.